# add pipe signs around every word in file

Tags: awk

I have the following file:

```
aaaa
bbbb
aaaabbbb
```

and I wish to have the following ouput:

```
|aaaa|
|bbbb|
|aaaabbbb|
```

I tried using:

```
for i in aaaa bbbb aaaabbbb
do
awk '{ sub ("${i}", "|"${i}"|", $1 }1' input
done
```

But I do not get the desired output. 
Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: i have the following file is confuses me..

Comment: Can a line have blank in it?  Suppose line 4 was `multiple words on a line`; what is the desired output?  Your example shows wrapping pipes around the whole line, but the title says 'every word' — so it isn't clear what's required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
awk '{print "|"$0"|"}' file
```

or

```
awk '{$0="|"$0"|"}1' file
```

---

or as twalberg points out, you can use `sed`

```
sed 's/^\|$/|/g' file
```

This replace start anchor `^` or end anchor `$` with `|`

Comment: Obligatory `sed` alternative: `sed -e 's/^/|/' -e 's/$/|/' file`. One case where the `awk` version is actually easier to type, I guess...

Comment: @twalberg Or just like this: `sed 's/^/|/;s/$/|/' file` or even shorter as in my updated post.

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1):

With **sed**:

```
sed 's/.*/|&|/g' File
```

`.*` will match the entire line. `&` => the pattern that was matched which will be `.* (entire line)`. Add `|` around the matched pattern.

For inplace substitution: `sed -i 's/.*/|&|/g' File`